# Cannot generate advanced report

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.2, reports, advanced-reporting

I'm using Magento 2, and I would like to generate Advanced Report.
However, it always shows 404 like this [image: Magento Advanced Report]

I've followed this guide, however it still shows 404.

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/reports/advanced-reporting.html

https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-fix-404-error-in-magento-2-advanced-reporting.html

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion for you.

There are a lot of extensions available on the marketplace.
I want to give you the best  suggestion [Advance Report Magento 2][1] by Elsner

The eCommerce business platform is becoming one of the most competitive markets. In such a setting, your company must stand out from the crowd in order to get noticed. And you can only do that if you have a complete view of your store's performance. So, buy the Advanced Reports Magento 2 Extension and increase the profit margin of your business.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check document from dev docs

`https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/reports/advanced-reporting.html`

You can check this guide, and focus in **Requirements**

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

To make Magento BI work, that is many factors; most of the time it's not just having it installed. Open the HTTP answer from your browser you will notice that the 404 page isn't a 404; it's a 401, which means **unauthorized**.

Make sure your website is public. It doesn't work with non-public websites.

[image: Magento Advanced Report 404]

#### Step 1 - Basic configuration

The first step is to follow the step-by-step from the official [Magento BI requirements](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/start/reporting/business-intelligence.html#advanced-reporting).

Make sure to whitelist these Magento BI IPs on your CDN and WAF.

Advance Reporting End point: https://advancedreporting.rjmetrics.com/

IPs:

```
34.206.147.74

35.172.154.189

54.144.21.42

3.85.182.28

52.73.51.61
```

#### Step 2 - Check cronjobs

Make sure your cronjobs are running, maybe they are configured but not running. You can download [Magerun 2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2) and run this command below regularly to ensure you don't miss hundreds of cronjobs.

```
./var/n98-magerun2.phar db:query "SELECT count(*) 'total' from cron_schedule WHERE status='missed' OR status='error' AND created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE);" | grep -v total
```

If you have hundreds of missed cronjobs, you will need to fix them first.

#### Step 3 - Prepare report folder

Then make sure the folder permissions are ok, and create a folder that would be automatically created, but we want to avoid possible gaps here.
Don't use sudo, in case you run it on Platform.sh and Magento Cloud.

```
mkdir pub/media/analytics
sudo find . -typef -execchmod664 {} \;
sudo find . -typed -execchmod775 {} \;
sudo find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -typef -execchmodg+w {} \;
sudo find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -typed -execchmodg+ws {} \;
sudo chmodu+x bin/magento
```

#### Step 4 - Reenable it

Go to your admin panel **Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Advanced Reporting** and disable, save, then enable, and save the config again.

[image: Magento BI Enable and Disable]

#### Step 5 - Reauthorize it

Then go to **System > Extensions > Integration** and **Reauthorize** it.

[image: Magento BI Reauthorize]

#### Step 6 - Token created

Then check if you have a token by using this query in your database.

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'analytics/general/token' \G
```

In case you don't have it, you need to figure out, why the last steps didn't create it.

#### Step 7 - Manually execution

The report cronjob runs each 24h, so I run Magerun 2 command to run the reports manually using the command below and selecting the following sequence.

```
./var/n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run
```

Sequence

1. **analytics_subscribe**
2. You can try to reauthorize at this stage if the first time without it doesn't work.
3. **analytics_update**
4. **analytics_collect_data**

#### Step 8 - Confirming report file

By running the command below you ensure that the report file is generated on your server side, and it's ready to be collected by Magento BI (each 24h from their side).

```
ls -ltr pub/media/analytics/
```

Running the command `bin/magento module:status` you can confirm if these essential modules are enabled.

```
Magento_AdminAnalytics

Magento_CatalogPageBuilderAnalytics

Magento_CatalogPageBuilderAnalyticsStaging

Magento_CmsPageBuilderAnalytics

Magento_CmsPageBuilderAnalyticsStaging

Magento_Analytics

Magento_GoogleAnalytics

Magento_CatalogAnalytics

Magento_PageBuilderAnalytics

Magento_QuoteAnalytics

Magento_ReviewAnalytics

Magento_BannerPageBuilderAnalytics

Magento_SalesAnalytics

Magento_CustomerAnalytics

Magento_PageBuilderAdminAnalytics

Magento_WishlistAnalytics
```

#### Step 9 - Possible extra errors

You might see logs from Magento BI, with 200 or 401.

```
zgrep  -i analytics /var/log/nginx/access.log* |  grep MagentoBI
```

Try this one too

```
zgrep analytics_collect_data var/log/support_report.log* | tail
```

On Plataform.sh or Magento Cloud you can run

```
zgrep  -i analytics /var/log/platform/xcykllamfhefo/access.log* |  grep MagentoBI
```

You might see a log like this example:

```
184.31.1.70 - - [28/Apr/2023:10:45:14 +0000] "GET /rest/V1/analytics/link HTTP/1.1" 200 190 "-" "MagentoBI"
23.195.73.31 - - [28/Apr/2023:13:43:29 +0000] "GET /rest/V1/analytics/link HTTP/1.1" 401 133 "-" "MagentoBI"
```

As you can see, my access log reported 401 because my WAF (Firewall) was blocking the external system connection.